# "Qui sommes nous ?" ou "Qui sommes-nous ?"

Tags: grammaire, questions, interrogative, inversion, trait-d-union

Je suis étudiant en informatique et nous devons réaliser un site web ainsi qu'un dossier écrit.
J'aimerais donc savoir quelle est la bonne formulation.

> - Qui sommes nous ?
> - Qui sommes-nous ? (avec un trait d'union)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Plusieurs sources fiables indiquent que le trait d’union **doit** être utilisé lorsque le verbe précède le pronom, que ce soit dans la tournure interrogative *(Qui **sommes-nous** ?)* ou dans les incises *(« C’est ainsi et pas autrement », **affirmé-je**<sup>1</sup>)* :

- Le Conjugueur du Figaro : [sommes-nous ?](https://leconjugueur.lefigaro.fr/conjugaison/verbe/etre_question.html)
- La Banque de dépannage linguistique, qui mentionne aussi l’ajout d’un T euphonique pour les pronoms de la troisième personne du singulier *(il, elle, on)* : [sera-t-il prêt pour... ?](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3353)
- L’université d’Ottawa : [une page](http://www.visezjuste.uottawa.ca/pages/orthographe/pronoms_personnels.html) sur les pronoms personnels et le trait d’union.
- La grammaire du français langue étrangère pour étudiants finnophones propose [une page](http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/533.html) sur l’interrogation directe qui expose les mêmes règles prescrivant le trait d’union.
- Même son de cloche chez [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntaxe_du_pronom_personnel_en_fran%C3%A7ais#Ant%C3%A9position_et_postposition_du_pronom_personnel_sujet), [Reverso](http://grammaire.reverso.net/5_3_03_trait_dunion_syntaxique.shtml), [Parlez-vous French ?](https://parlez-vous-french.com/poser-question-francais/), le Bon usage *(§110 dans la 14<sup>e</sup> édition)* et quantité d’autres ressources, beaucoup trop nombreuses pour être toutes citées ici.

---

Quant au graphique [nGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Qui+sommes-nous+%3F%2CQui+sommes+nous+%3F&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CQui%20sommes%20-%20nous%20%3F%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CQui%20sommes%20nous%20%3F%3B%2Cc0) proposé dans une autre réponse, qui s’en sert comme levier pour considérer que la forme sans trait d’union existe dans les livres imprimés, il n’est pas exact. Il importe, quand on obtient un résultat si controversé, de suivre les liens sous le graphique pour en inspecter visuellement les sources. Et que **trouvons-nous** alors ?

- Dans TOUS les cas, un excepté, on trouve simplement, de la façon attendue : ***qui sommes-nous***
  **→ Faux positifs**
- Et un cas qui fait [exception](https://books.google.ca/books?id=pOIAKqaMVAYC&pg=PA28&dq=%22qui+sommes+nous?%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjzibqrrprfAhVLm-AKHeX2Au8Q6AEIOTAC#v=onepage&q=%22qui%20sommes%20nous%3F%22&f=false), duquel on se gardera néanmoins de conclure que les éditeurs impriment contre la règle générale :

  > `Autre 7.`   – Nous **qui sommes** !
  >   `Autre 4.`   – **Nous** !

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>**affirmé-je** selon l’ancienne orthographe, ou [**affirmè-je**](https://leconjugueur.lefigaro.fr/frtraitunionquestion.php), selon la nouvelle (mais dans les deux cas, **un trait d’union**).</sub>

Answer (score 8):

Seule la forme avec trait d'union est correcte.

Quand un pronom personnel suit un verbe à la forme interrogative et qu'il en est le sujet, un trait d'union doit être présent.

La réforme orthographique de 1990 n'a pas affecté cette règle et la forme *qui sommes nous*, même si on la rencontre parfois, est donc toujours considérée comme fautive.

Answer (score 3):

Hyphens are used notably:

(i) To link the verb to a following personal pronoun, or on, or ce (pronoun):

> allez-vous; dépêche-toi ! arrive-t-il (note the insertion of t for the reasons of euphony); donnez-le-moi; dit-on ? est-ce ? puis-je ? allons-y !

(ii) to join ci or a là to the world they qualify:

> celui-ci; cette femme-là; là-bas

(iii) to link a disjunctive pronoun and the following adjective même (=self):

> moi-même; eux-mêmes; soi-même;

(iv) in compound numerals

(v) in numerous other compound parts of speech, e.g.:

> chou-fleur; Grande-Bretagne; peut-être; quelques-uns; au-dessus de; etc.

Nevertheless, there is no always a clear logical rule governing the presence or absence of the hyphen thus one has to consult a dictionary for such words.

References:

1. (Mostly) H. Ferrar's A French Reference Grammar (Oxford).
2. M. Offold's [A Student Grammar of French](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/student-grammar-of-french/BC2BE0B8A4E93DD47D73C457C7E15D13) (CUP)

I guess forms like “sommes nous” are used in quick communication like emails or text messages (especially between young people) but they are not considered correct French and a beginner should totally avoid them.
I also think that their possible absence will chock many native speakers (if not all).

Answer (score -8):

Les deux formes sont  [utilisées](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Qui+sommes-nous+%3F%2CQui+sommes+nous+%3F&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CQui%20sommes%20-%20nous%20%3F%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CQui%20sommes%20nous%20%3F%3B%2Cc0) mais la fréquence de la seconde est bien plus grande ; si vous préférez simplifier vous pouvez utiliser la première forme comme ont commencé à le faire des utilisateurs français du langage. Cependant,  l'usage de la première ne date que d'un passé récent et reste peu courant; la seconde est donc la forme traditionnelle qui est considérée pour l'instant la seule correcte.

Il faut savoir cependant que la possibilité sans trait d'union n'existe pas seulement pour « [Qui sont-ils ?](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Qui+%C3%AAtes-vous+%3F%2CQui+%C3%AAtes+vous+%3F%2CQui+suis-je+%3F%2CQui+suis+je%3F%2CQui+es-tu+%3F%2CQui+es+tu+%3F%2CQui+est-il+%3F%2CQui+est+il+%3F%2CQui+sont-ils%2CQui+sont+ils+%3F&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CQui%20%C3%AAtes%20-%20vous%20%3F%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CQui%20%C3%AAtes%20vous%20%3F%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CQui%20suis%20-%20je%20%3F%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CQui%20suis%20je%20%3F%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CQui%20es%20-%20tu%20%3F%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CQui%20es%20tu%20%3F%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CQui%20est%20-%20il%20%3F%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CQui%20sont%20-%20ils%3B%2Cc0) », « Qui est-il ? » (influence du t qui est ajouté parfois pour l'euphonie?) alors qu'elle existe pour toutes les autres personnes ; la forme avec le trait d'union est toujours et de loin, la plus fréquente.

Comment: merci de votre réponse claire et précise. Et aussi la découverte du site google book. merci =)

Comment: "Qui es-tu ?" et non pas "Qui est-tu ?"

Comment: Le descriptivisme a ses limites...

Comment: @Saint-Jacques Je pense que vous ne vous en tenez pas suffisamment aux mots exacts de mon énoncé qui sont « si vous préférez simplifier »; il n'y a en ces mots aucune demande et seulement l'intention de ne pas laisser perdre de vue à l'utilisateur du langage que si une certaine partie des écrivains français, si minime soit cette partie, a pu se permettre de passer outre les directives traditionnelles il n'y a pas de raison de refuser catégoriquement cette possibilité à un écrivain étranger qui peut lui-même/elle-même avoir acquis les mêmes convictions; vous aurez dû constater dans les ngram,

Comment: @Saint-Jacques qu'il existe une proportion non négligeable de cas pour lesquels le trait d'union manque ; je ne crois pas qu'il s'agisse d'erreur mais d'une véritable tolérance dans le but d'apporter un changement ; on tolère tellement de changements dans le français de nos jours! Pourquoi être partial en ce qui concerne celui-ci ? Remarquez aussi que j'insiste sur le fait que la forme traditionnelle est la seule considérée comme correcte (ce après un rappel à l'ordre par jlliagre). Il me semble cependant que vous ne voyez aucune importance dans les révélations fournies par les ngrams.

Comment: @Saint-Jacques presque 10 % des « Qui sommes-nous? » dans la matière écrite de nos jours sont écrits sans trait d'union. Cela est loin d'être négligeable. (voir ngram)

Comment: @LPH Quand bien même ce pourcentage serait vrai, il n'en reste pas moins que la question porte sur « **la** **bonne** formulation ». Elle attend donc clairement une réponse prescriptiviste, pas une réponse qui suggère d'utiliser une forme très minoritaire qu'aucune référence ne valide, ou qui laisse entendre qu'un relâchement de la règle est attendu.